# Stress Testing in node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on a project that is focusing on chat. I have developed the chat architecture and test with 5 devices and it is working fine. But practically it can have more than 1000 users at a time per chat room. But it is not feasible to get those amount of users in a test environment. I need to create those users and random communication architecture programmatically. Is there any tool or module available that can create huge number of users per room and randomly communicate with each others so that I can stress test of our app?

Comment: you can search on NPM with keyword stress and you find a lot of modules : [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=stress) like `stress-node` module.

Comment: @Sachacr thanks for your reply. But it is not giving me the options to create lots of users. I need to have a module that at east creates those huge number of users for socket

Comment: I think in stress node the option `concurrent: 5` do 5 concurrent connections and emulate 5 users. 
So with `amount: 1000` it makes 200 request per user.

And you can do post of random message by setting `data` option and `method` to POST.

Comment: might be a good addition from you if you can write such module and open source it